# Option to start Android app on a particular site instead of the network feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When you start the Android Stack Exchange app, it opens up to a general network-wide question feed. If I'm using a web browser, I don't start on the Stack Exchange home — I start on my top site because it's usually what I'm most curious to check.

Can we add a similar option in the Android app to start on a specific site instead of the general feed?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I hope that properly conveys what you are trying to ask/request

Comment: Related, it's equally difficult to _stay_ on a site, starting from the network feed. So, if I start from the network feed and end up on cooking, it's not exactly obvious how to _not_ go back to the network / hot feed.

Comment: Navigation in the Android app confuses me; I can never seem to figure out how to get, and stay, where I want to be.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Yup, an improvement. Thanks.